# what is the usage にまで?

Tags: grammar, particles

海外**にまで**知られ始める。does the に work here as "by"? (人**に**変だと言われる- this kind of に? like it works usually with passive verbs?) and まで just strenghtens it? Am i right, or am i missing something? i've never seen にまで

Comment: Not an answer, but it may well be に + まで, where まで is understood as "even" (similar to も or さえ) rather than "until" in a spatial or temporal sense, i.e. "to be known even overseas".

Comment: 'Like it usually works with passive verbs'?  知**られ**始める *is* passive

Comment: @Angelos that was not my question, my question was if the に marks the word that performs this "passive" action. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: It is *(known) even **to** (people) abroad*.

Answer (score 2):

That まで in this case means "even/to the point of".

For examples:

> 彼女が好きすぎて、足の匂いまで嗅ぎたくなります

> I like my girlfriend too much that I even started wanting to smell her feet's odor.

As you can see, it expresses an hyperbole.

にまで is just combining に and まで.

All in all, your sentence means:

> 海外にまで知られ始める

> To start being known **even** overseas.

Comment: so the に here marks by who is the action done?

Comment: Yes. basically that.